# How to view the SQL error message in a Delphi's DBX transaction?

Tags: delphi, dbx

I've seen this somewhere in SO some time ago, but I couldn't find it now.

I remember that one of the error events in some component (TSQLDataSet, TDataSetProvider, TClientDataSet or else) would give me the error message as returned by the database server itself, but I cannot recall it.

Does someone knows what I am talking about?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TClientDataSet.OnReconcileError contains a parameter of type EReconcileError which includes the error message, context and code. This data contains the message from the database server.

Answer (score 0):

Of course EReconcileError only helps if that is the particular type of database error you have.
For all errors first look at the E.Messaage string, which gives you a description of the problem. Not always the same as the exact server text i think - it dpends also which database driver you are using - I am more familiar with the TMySQLConnection, but it's still a DBExpress driver...
Chris